# Flutter get push notification device token without firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am developing a cross platform app with flutter and I haven't integrated firebase in my project. I am using PHP as a backend.

I want to setup the push notifications using APNS. I have generated .pem files to send in APNS. but i don't know how to get the device token for the notifications. I have the UDID but its not working with the APNS. APNS requires the device token.

Using the following code i get the permissions

```
NotificationPermissions.getNotificationPermissionStatus()
        .then((status) {
          print(status);
      switch (status) {
        case PermissionStatus.denied:
          return permDenied;
        case PermissionStatus.granted:
          return permGranted;
        case PermissionStatus.unknown:
          return permUnknown;
        case PermissionStatus.provisional:
          return permProvisional;
        default:
          return null;
      }
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are the instructions: [Registering Your App with APNs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/registering_your_app_with_apns). Pretty simple to do on native side if requirements are simple and when targeting only iOS.

Comment: but i am not using native code. i am using flutter

Comment: Push notifications are always implemented on native side. There are just libraries that do it for you, but there is no reason why you couldn't do it yourself.

Comment: i don't know native codes. before flutter i have done with react native and ionic. i have done with php code APNs. But now the issue is they asking for device token. before i done with UDID. thats why i am stuck